# Fusion Tables numeric ID

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm working on a multiple query with Fusion Table. Till yesterday I used numericID but today creating a new Table, FT shows no numeric ID in the about menu. I tried to change NUmeric ID with Ecrypted one, but it doesn't work. This is the page:

http://siti-torino.hostei.com/test/test_09_02.html ( `numeric ID`)
http://siti-torino.hostei.com/test/test_09_03.html ( `Encrypted ID`)

It's quite clear that the query works correctly (the counter show the right result), but the script can't update the map. So I suppose the problem is at line 94-95

```
searchTracks = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(fusionTableId, { query: searchStr});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the "old syntax", that doesn't work with encrypted ids.

```
new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(fusionTableId, { query: searchStr});
```

Use the [documented syntax](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer)

```
 new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({ query: {[FusionTablesQuery object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesQuery)}});
```

[Example of your page](http://www.geocodezip.com/siti-torino_hostel_com_test_09_02a.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quickly reply, but I'm really dummy, and I can't understand how to change the script with new syntax using my query string. Can you suggest me more detailed instructions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can provide more details on how to convert your query to the new syntax if you provide more details on your query.  This is not enough "searchStr", need to know what that string is, or you can look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesQuery) (link also in my answer), and break it out yourself.

Comment: I tried to break it out, and I'll try again, but every help is wellcome. Anyway, the code is this page http://siti-torino.hostei.com/test/test_09_02.html but it just a part of a more complex project that you can see at this adress http://siti-torino.hostei.com/test/index.html

Comment: Where is the code where you tried to break it out and ran into trouble? That should be easier to fix that than to create it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I solved troubles using .replace coommand to change my query string. You can find my WIP page at this adress http://siti-torino.hostei.com/test

Comment: Done! BTW suggestions for more efficient ways to compile the pages are really welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I'm trying to pick up the piece after a coworker left. I'm not a programmer. 
We beleive the site might be having a problem not recognizing the new I'ds as a String compared to the old numeric Values

//Setting the lat lng

```
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long);
     var myOptions = {
              zoom: zoomLevel,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

        map.setOptions(myOptions);
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer "1QzYXB7nkb7drbz66HMmq3_d7Dut_Gulx2aZEC2Q"; 
        layer.setMap(map);

        if(addressMarker)
            addressMarker.setMap(null);                     
        addressMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: latlng
        });         

        infowindow.open(map,addressMarker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(addressMarker, 'click', function() 
        {
            infowindow.open(map,addressMarker);
        });             
      }
}
```